# how to retrieve data from database and display in textbox using php ajax and jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

can anyone tell me how to retrieve data from database and display it in text box in html by using php ajax and jquery? it will just only display if the button is click. Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1):

register.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>registion</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>

        $(function () {
            $('#btn').click(function () {
              $.post(
                  'checkUserName.php',{
                      username:$('#username').val()
                  },function(data,textStatus){
                      $('#result').html(data);
                });
            });
        });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>registion</h1>
    <form action="" method="post">
        userName：<input type="text" name="username" id="username">
        <input type="button" value="Verify userName" id="btn">
        <br>
        <span id="result"></span>


    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

checkUserName.php

```
<?php

$uname = $_POST['username'];

$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','root','db_user');
$query = "SELECT * from tb_user where name = '$uname' ";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
$nums = mysqli_num_rows($result);

//echo $query;
//echo $nums;
if($nums > 0){
    echo "Username already exist";
}else{
    echo "Username OK";
}

mysqli_close($conn);
```

Answer (score 0):

Next time please post together what have you done so far. From there only the community will be able to help you.

HTML Code :

```
<input type="text" id="input-box">
<button type="button" id="btn_get">Click</button>
```

Ajax Code :

```
$('#btn_get').on('click', function(){
 $.ajax({
   type    : "get",
   url     : '/path/to/php/file',       
   success : function(data)
   {
     $('#input-box').val(data);
   }
 });
});
```

PHP Code :

```
//get data from db here
$data = 'foo';
echo $data;
```

Comment: thank you! by the way i don't have any code that I've done.